# Logging to windows application event log

Tags: sql-server, logging, ssms, event-log

Hi this is basically what I want to do in sql server management studio.

Whenever any user tries to delete or update the data in the table, it needs to be logged into the Windows Application event log.

Is there anywhere I can reference how to do this? I can't find anything.

Thanks

Full Question:

As the Products table is a very important table, the company wishes to track selected changes to the
table. Whenever any user tries to delete or update the data in the table, it should be logged into the
Windows Application event log. However, there is no need to undo the changes as it may be a
legitimate change.

Comment: This seems like a lot of data going to be logged. What's the purpose? Are you trying to see who is responsible for changing data? Can we log the changes in other target?

Comment: Hi this is a question from my school assignment not for real world purpose. I've added the full question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [SQL Server Audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) for that. When you [create a server audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/create-a-server-audit-and-server-audit-specification?view=sql-server-2017#to-create-a-server-audit), specify audit destination to be `Windows Application Log`. For more information, see [CREATE SERVER AUDIT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-server-audit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Since it is a school assignment, I believe it will be the best for you to try write it yourself. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Realize this is an old question but I recently had to deal w/something like this again myself. I used the following (although you may/may not run into permission issues depending on how you run it):

```
EXEC master..xp_logevent 50001, 'My log message here...', 'INFORMATIONAL'
```

More info [here](https://en.dirceuresende.com/blog/undocumented-sql-server-extended-procedures/)